# Configuration for page redirect

Tags: .htaccess, wamp

I have WAMP installed, and a project at in `E:/wamp/www/project/index.php` Links from `index.php` redirect to `show.php` I am using the below `.htaccess` script to be able to make URL in `show.php` appear as `/article-title` instead of what it normally does i.e `show.php?id=xxx`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule  (.*)$ show.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But, the above `.htaccess` file which is found in `project/` along side the index/show page does not seem to work. It does not even show me the project folder, when I go to `www/`

I don't know where the problem is, and *rewrite-module* is on

Comment: @Prix Nope. If I followed the above method, I am not even able to see the `project` folder from `http://localhost`

Comment: Nope. the entire `project` folder is not being showed up. not even if I access `index.php`

Comment: @Prix Not sure if you read the whole question. With the `.htaccess` sitting on the root folder of my project i.e.( `c:/wamp/www/project/htaccess` or `localhost/project/.htaccess` ) I can't access the side, nor even see the folder or any part of the file if I go to `locahost/index.php` or even `localhost/` on the flip side, if I removed the `.htaccess` file, I can see everything, and access my projects index page from `locahost/project/index.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your article URL is like this:

```
http://localhost/project/1122-some-title-comes-here
```

You can use this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^project/(\d+)-([\w-]+)/?$ /project/show.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If you want your articles from the root folder like this:

```
http://localhost/1122-some-title-comes-here
```

You can change the above to:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(\d+)-([\w-]+)/?$ /project/show.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The above conditions means, if folder, files and symbolic links are false, rewrite it.
The rule itself `^(\d+)-([\w-]+)/?$` if it start with digits and a dash and contains additional alphanumeric characters and dash and end or not with `/` internally redirect to:

```
/project/show.php?id=$1
```

The `$1` means to pass the result of the parenthesis from the rule to the id which is `(\d+)` which in our URL example would mean the number `1122`.

Answer (score 0):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html
"The RewriteBase directive specifies the URL prefix to be used for per-directory (htaccess) RewriteRule directives that substitute a relative path."